# Exception Handling From Imported Package

Tags: python-3.x, exception, logging, web-scraping, try-except

I am working with twint to download some twitter followers. Every now and then, twint will throw an error when it cannot find the "more" button. This is described here: https://github.com/twintproject/twint/issues/340.

My workaround is to loop through until I've gotten the number of followers I'd like. However, I would like to keep track of the number of times that the "more" button was not found using cons_errors. Looking at feed.py, https://github.com/twintproject/twint/blob/master/twint/feed.py, an `IndexError` is raised when this button is not found. How can I track when this happens?

This is the code from within feed.py that raises the error:

```
def Follow(response):
    logme.debug(__name__+':Follow')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
    follow = soup.find_all("td", "info fifty screenname")
    cursor = soup.find_all("div", "w-button-more")
    try:
        cursor = findall(r'cursor=(.*?)">', str(cursor))[0]
    except IndexError:
        logme.critical(__name__+':Follow:IndexError')

    return follow, cursor
```

The code I am using is as follows but never catches the exception, rather,`twint.run.Followers(c)` prints this error message to the console: `CRITICAL:root:twint.feed:Follow:IndexError` and the loop continues iterating without ever printing `in except block` or incrementing cons_errors. In other words, the try is always successful.

```
import twint
import time

c = twint.Config()
c.Limit = 1000 #download 1,000 followers
c.Username = "MarketGoldberg" #random account chosen with a 79 followers
c.Output = "followers.txt" #where to save followers
c.Resume = "resume.txt" #user to pick up from if called again

download_rounds = 2  # intentionally high to force error, all 79 followers will be downloaded in the first iteration
cons_errors = 0  # number of consecutive errors received from twint.
while download_rounds > 0 and cons_errors <= 10:
    try:
        twint.run.Followers(c)
        cons_errors = 0
        download_rounds -= 1
    except IndexError as err:
        print("in except block")
        cons_errors += 1
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the exception is already caught in the package, you can't catch it a second time. You could modify the package, remove the exception handling and handle it yourself. Or you could add a [logging handler](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#handlers) which counts log messages that end with `:Follow:IndexError`.

Comment: Thanks @nicola. I've added the function from within the package which already implements logging into my question. Is there a way from me to tap into that log? I don't want to modify the package. Thank you.